# How to Convert your gin go app to severless Vercel

Tags: go, vercel

I have `main.go`

which looks like this

```
func main() {
    app := config.App()
    env := app.Env
    gin := gin.Default()
    gin.Use(CORSMiddleware())
    db := app.Db
    route.Setup(env,db, gin)
    gin.Run(":" + env.Port)
}

func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(204)
            return
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

I want to deploy this `vercel`.

I went through few resources:

- https://github.com/TBXark/g4vercel
- https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/go
- [How to use Go Gin in vercel serveless functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72203014/how-to-use-go-gin-in-vercel-serveless-functions)

But I am still unsure on how to do it. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Vercel is primarily designed for deploying front-end applications and serverless functions, why do you want to do go app deployment?

Answer (score 1):

first of all create a folder and move `main.go` file into it, then create another file here, `api/index.go` with this content :

```
package handler

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "net/http"
)

func CORSMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization, accept, origin, Cache-Control, X-Requested-With")
        c.Writer.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, OPTIONS, GET, PUT, DELETE")

        if c.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" {
            c.AbortWithStatus(http.StatusNoContent)
            return
        }
        c.Next()
    }
}

func Handler(c *gin.Context) {
    gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
    app := config.App()
    env := app.Env
    gin := gin.Default()
    gin.Use(CORSMiddleware())
    db := app.Db
    route.Setup(env, db, gin)
    gin.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
}
```

now you need to create two files in the root directory of your project, first `vercel.json` with this content :

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/api/(.*)",
            "dest": "/api/index.go"
        }
    ]
}
```

second, create `go.mod` file and try to run this command to initialize the Go module!

```
go mod init
```

at the end try to run this command to install all necessary files and dependencies

```
go get -u github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

ok, now for deploying your app, just run this in terminal :

```
$ vercel
```

your app should now be deployed on `Vercel` as a serverless and you can access it at the generated URL!

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your `main.go` represents a fully running application based on the Gin framework in Go, and you want to [deploy it on Vercel](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/deployments/overview). However, Vercel is not designed to host traditional web servers (such as your Gin application). That means you will need to refactor your application into serverless functions to achieve this.

Start by separating each Handler into its own file: Serverless functions are designed to be simple, single-purpose pieces of code. In your current setup, you likely have multiple routes handled by the `gin` instance. Each of these should be extracted into its own serverless function, each in a separate `.go` file.

For example, if you have a handler for the route `/api/users`, you could create a file named `api-users.go`.

```golang
// api-users.go
package handler

import (
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func Handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Creating new gin engine
    g := gin.New()
    // Your handler logic
    g.GET("/api/users", func(c *gin.Context) {
        // ... your handler logic here ...
        c.JSON(200, gin.H{
            "message": "Hello from /api/users",
        })
    })

    // running gin engine
    g.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Then update your [`vercel.json` configuration file](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration): You need to tell Vercel that these new `.go` files are serverless functions, and they should be treated as such.

```json
{
    "functions": {
        "api/users.go": {
            "runtime": "vercel/go@0.2.0"
        }
        // add other routes here
    }
}
```

`"api/users.go"` should match the file name and location of your serverless function file. Adjust this to match where you have stored your serverless function files.

You also need to add a [`go.mod` file to the root of your directory](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/functions/serverless-functions/runtimes/go#go-dependencies) to tell Vercel what dependencies it needs to install.

```golang
module YOUR_MODULE_NAME

go 1.20

require github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.9.1
```

Finally, push your code to your GitHub/GitLab/Bitbucket repository and connect it to Vercel. Vercel will then deploy your Go serverless functions.

---

> How can I run it locally?

To run your Vercel serverless functions locally, you can use [Vercel's own command-line interface (CLI)](https://vercel.com/docs/cli) which includes a development command ([`vercel dev`](https://vercel.com/docs/cli/dev)) to simulate the Vercel environment on your local machine.

```bash
npm install -g vercel
vercel dev
```

You can access your serverless functions at `http://localhost:3000` (or whatever port is shown in your terminal). The paths to your serverless functions will correspond to the function file paths in your project.

For instance, if you have a serverless function in `api/users.go`, you can access this function by going to `http://localhost:3000/api/users`.

Other example: "**[#DevHack: Specifying what to run on Vercel dev](https://dev.to/estruyf/devhack-specifying-what-to-run-on-vercel-dev-49hn)** ", from [Elio Struyf](https://github.com/estruyf).

Comment: How can I run it locally?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the key steps to deploy your Gin API server on Vercel:

1. Create a api/ folder with your Go code.
2. Add a go.mod file to specify dependencies.
3. Create a api/go.mod file:

```
module example.com/api

go 1.20

require (
  github.com/gin-gonic/gin v1.8.2
)
```

4. Add a api/main.go file with your server code:

```golang
package main

import (
  "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
  r := gin.Default()
  // routes here 
  
  r.Run() 
}
```

5. Create a api/vercel.json config file:

```json
{
  "builds": [{
    "src": "./main.go",
    "use": "@vercel/go",
    "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb" }
  }]
}
```

6. Push to GitHub/GitLab repo
7. Import repo to Vercel and deploy
8. Set ENV vars on Vercel for things like DATABASE_URL

This will build your Go server into a serverless function app on Vercel. You can then add your routes, middleware, etc like normal Gin.

Comment: Error: Could not find an exported function in "api/main.go"